# Oracle MERGE raise ORA-00904 error

Tags: oracle, merge, ora-00904

I am using merge command to insert a non-exist record into table. When I use simple insert command it works fine. If I use merge system always alert ORA-00904: "T"."GROUP_COMPANY_ID" invalid identifier. Once I change the ON condition to (1=1) to force be true then the merge command works fine.

What the original merge statement goes to wrong? I am very sure the table was created without double quoted name so there is not case issue here.

```
create table test
(
  create_date      DATE not null,
  group_company_id CHAR(16) not null
)

-- This is okay
INSERT INTO test (create_date, group_company_id) VALUES (TO_DATE('20100531', 'YYYYMMDD'), 'abc');

-- This one will raise ORA-00904 error
MERGE INTO test T
USING (SELECT 'abc' AS group_company_id FROM DUAL) C
   ON (T.group_company_id = C.group_company_id)
-- ON (1 = 1)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     INSERT (create_date, group_company_id)
     VALUES (TO_DATE('20100531', 'YYYYMMDD'), 'abc')
WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE SET group_company_id = 'abc';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qualify the column names with the table aiases in the `insert` and `update` clauses

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (T.create_date, T.group_company_id)
  VALUES (TO_DATE('20100531', 'YYYYMMDD'), 'abc')
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET T.group_company_id = 'abc';
```

Edit:

```
MERGE INTO test  
USING DUAL   
ON (group_company_id = 'abc') 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN      
      INSERT VALUES (TO_DATE('20100531', 'YYYYMMDD'), 'abc');
```

Comment: Disambiguate `group_company_id` between `T` and `C`

Comment: Thanks but still cannot work. The ORA-00904 occur at same place.

Comment: I ignore the C with "ON (T.group_company_id = 'abc')", same error. I ignore all the alias T and C, same error.

Answer (score 8):

You can't update a column that you're joining on.

Comment: Actually I want to insert record if not exists in table. So the column "group_company_id" is necessary to check (join condition) and must be inserted.

Comment: You don't need the `WHEN MATCHED` clause to set `group_company_id = 'abc'` when its already matched to `abc`.

Comment: It's fine to do that with a merge, but you can't update a column whilst simultaneously using it in a join.

Comment: Without "WHEN MATCHED" the syntax is incorrect and oracle refuse to execute it. Oracle alert: ORA-00905 missing keyword

Comment: `update` and `insert` clauses are optional in a `merge` command. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm

Comment: Thanks all I' solved the problem that I change the WHEN MATCHED to update another column which is not listed on join condition.

Comment: +1: in 10gR2 the above query raises the much more unambiguous error: `ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: "T"."GROUP_COMPANY_ID"`

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't hurl ORA-00904, it hurls the self-explanatory ORA-38104

```
SQL> MERGE INTO test T
USING (SELECT 'abc' AS group_company_id FROM DUAL) C
   ON (T.group_company_id = C.group_company_id)
-- ON (1 = 1)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     INSERT (create_date, group_company_id)
     VALUES (TO_DATE('20100531', 'YYYYMMDD'), 'abc')
WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE SET group_company_id = 'abc';
  2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9     ON (T.group_company_id = C.group_company_id)
       *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated:
"T"."GROUP_COMPANY_ID"


SQL>
```

I'm running 11gR2 - perhaps the behaviour is different on an earlier release.  Anyway the solution is quite simple: don't bother with the MATCHED branch:

```
SQL> MERGE INTO test T
USING (SELECT 'abc' AS group_company_id FROM DUAL) C
   ON (T.group_company_id = C.group_company_id)
-- ON (1 = 1)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     INSERT (create_date, group_company_id)
     VALUES (TO_DATE('20100531', 'YYYYMMDD'), 'abc')
  2    3    4    5    6    7    8  /

0 rows merged.

SQL>
```

This syntax was not valid when MERGE was introduced in 9i: we had to include both branches.  But it has been supported since 10g.

If you are using 9i and so need a MATCHED branch, you must update a column which is not included in the joining clause.  That would be CREATE_DATE in your example,